# Jquery append x times the slide value

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, append

I basically created a slider using `bootstrap-slider.js`. If one slides at the slider the value changes as expected, now I want to append some HTML the same numbers as my value in my slider. Code looks like this so far:

```
$("#slider").slider();
$("#slider").on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
    $("#SliderVal").text(slideEvt.value);
    $("div").mouseup(function(){
        $("#sliderAppend").append('<div><p>test</p></div>');
    });
});
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<input id="slider" data-slider-id='slider' style="width:600px;"type="text" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="1" data-slider-value="0"/>
<span id="CurrentSliderValLabel">Current:
    <span id="SliderVal">X</span> appends
</span>

<div id="sliderAppend">

</div>
```

So for example if one drags the slider to 10 and releases the mouse, the function should append `<div><p>test</p></div>` 10 times.

Comment: It sounds like you just need to loop from `0` to  `slideEvt.value`

Comment: hmm ok could you show me a short snippet of how excatly you mean this

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Comment: Thanks but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using events as follows:

```
$("#slider").slider({
  change : function(e, slider){
        $('#sliderAppend').empty();

        for(var i=0;i<slider.value;i++)
          $('#sliderAppend').append('<div><p>test</p></div>');
  },
  slide : function(e , slider){
    $('#slideVal').val(slider.value)
  }
});
```

For the appending it'self, as mentioned here a simple `for` really fits.

http://jsfiddle.net/ay6rw8sc/3/

Comment: Thanks this is really strange somehow it will not append anything hmm

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: The slider works but it does not add this <div><p>test</p></div>

Comment: Thus I do not have an error or anything in the console

Comment: Please fiddle your code it will be much easier to see what's going on, my fiddle example works fine.

Comment: @JohnDoesLegacy your fiddle is broken (missing links to the required libraries).

Comment: hm I thought I linked all of them could you tell me which one you used

Comment: You could just fork my fiddle and the code to your's.

Comment: hmm I am not used to jsfiddle like how do I see your libraries there?

Comment: I got it now it works. I had to remove <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slider/bootstrap-slider.js"></script> unfortunatly

Comment: How do I change the range like to want to reduce it from 100 to 50

Comment: You can get all relevant information in the official github page https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider